# Keeping a user logged in on application untill they log out, when i log in with a user and navigate between pages, user automatically logged out

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, back4app

currently building react & back4app project. when a user signs in and navigates to a new page they are automatically signed out and have to log back in again. I am using the currentUser method and wondering do i need to call this on every page to keep the user signed in.

```
 // Function that will return current user and also update current username
      const getCurrentUser = async function () {
      const currentUser = await Parse.User.current();
    // Update state variable holding current user
      setCurrentUser(currentUser);
      return currentUser;
  };
```

Comment: The code you are sharing does not look to have something wrong but the problem that you are facing is probably related on how you are calling this code and you are architecting your application. Would you mind to share more details on where this code is?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo i have this code called in the Sign-In component only. Should i call this code on each page to retrieve the current user.

Comment: You need to store this state in a component that is shared by all pages.